# “a whipsawing trade standoff” mean?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> The collapse of the deal could aggravate tensions between Washington and Beijing amid a **whipsawing** trade standoff that has chilled relations between the world's top two economies.

According to [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whipsaw):

> ... figuratively to describe situations in which someone or something is doubly "cut" or hurt....

But I am unsure where "**the doubly cut or hurt**" sits in this context.

Here is the [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/qualcomm-nxp-deal-scrapped-china-says-still-open-013054411--business.html).

Comment: I've never encountered such a usage before. I'm not even sure I've ever encountered even a more literal instance of ***whipsaw***, but without bothering to look it up, I think I can safely assume the reference is to a very long "bendy, springy" saw (such as might be used by two lumberjacks, one on each side of a large tree). Given the sharp teeth, something like that would be a potentially dangerous thing as it whips back and forth cutting into the tree trunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metaphor refers to the back-and-forth nature of trade wars, their tit-for-tat aspect.

P.S. **whipsawing** and the noun it modifies, **standoff**, are something of a mixed metaphor.  A standoff is a stalemate or deadlock: all whipsawing has ceased when a stalemate is reached.

Comment: I wish I could give you a second upvote for pointing out the disconnect between stand-off and whipsawing. I wonder whether our political climate would be less contentious if some journalists focused more on being accurate and less on colorful language.

Answer (score 1):

The trade standoff hurts both China and USA.

Comment: The normal usage is like: *wage earners were whipsawed by inflation and high taxes.* But the usage in that article seems a bit different.